# Sort Pages According To List VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, ms-word

I have a PDF file that contains 500+ pages containing a unique number on each page. First I wanted to sort them with Acrobat PDF Pro DC Actions/JavaScript but its hard and I don't understand Java at all.

Then I realized that I can open PDFs in MS Word 365 as well and when I opened the same doc in MS Word 365 it is searchable.

Now I want a VBA code to rearrange these pages according to a list that I provide in XLSX or CSV or TXT etc. format and save it as a new file.

[File Before Sort Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xJqc.png)

[Sort List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuanl.png)

[File After Sort Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0NcC.png)

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.
I have tried to do it with https://acrobatusers.com/assets/uploads/actions/find_highlight_and_extract.sequ which is available at https://acrobatusers.com/actions-exchange/. But problem is that it extracts pages randomly and its code is not understandable to me. So that's why I want to do it with VBA.

Comment: And PDF is computer generated and its structure is quite firm as I mentioned that its searchable.

Comment: If the PDF is computer-generated (no surprises there) any page rearranging should be done in the application that creates it in the first place.

Comment: Yes exactly. But the thing is I get this PDF from other source I do not generate it.

Comment: Thanks K J. But arranging 500+ pages and remembering the sort order will be a headache and a time consuming process. And almost all page needs sorting.

Comment: «the thing is I get this PDF from other source I do not generate it» So have you asked the 'other source' to produce an output with your required page order? In any event, Word is likely not the appropriate tool for this, simply because Word tends to change the formatting of imported PDFs.

Comment: @macropod thanks for your kind reply. They are totally not interested to help me in this, and I don't know the reason for it as well. I just receive it and it's my headache to reorder them.

Comment: In which case you should look at using a product like Adobe Acrobat Pro, which can be automated, to do the reordering.

Comment: Yes already using Acrobat Pro DC and if JavaScript/Action available to do what I want please share.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sort-pages-according-to-list-vba-javascript-actions.1224099/. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I have asked the same question on MrExcel here (https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sort-pages-according-to-list-vba-javascript-actions.1224099/) as well.

Comment: Hi,
Following is the answer...
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/sort-pages-according-to-list-vba-javascript-actions.1224099/post-5988806